# Vim: how to create key mapping to :edit and jump to last line?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I mapped key <kbd>F2</kbd> to refresh (`:edit`) currently opened file. I'm using this when watching a log file to update the screen when file has been updated outside (new lines added at the end of a log file).

```
nnoremap <silent> <F2> :edit<CR>
```

I would like to jump to the end of the file after it has been refreshed.

How do I create key mapping which does `:edit` and jump to end of the file (shortcut `G`) at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idiomatic way to position the cursor in the just opened (or reopened) file
is to use the `+`-argument of the `:edit` command (see `:help +cmd`).
Although the general syntax allows to execute any command, there are special
cases for navigating to a certain line by a pattern matching text on that line
(`+/` followed by the pattern), or by a line number (`+` followed by the
number).  If the number is omitted in the latter form, it is assumed to be the
last line of the file.

In such a way, to reload the current file positioning the cursor on the last
line, one can use the command

```
:edit +$
```

or

```
:edit + %
```

It is possible to shorten these commands by using `:e` instead of `:edit` and
leaving out an optional space before the `+`-argument.

```
:e+$
```

or

```
:e+ %
```

The corresponding mappings would take the form

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F2> :edit +$<CR>
```

and

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F2> :edit + %<CR>
```

Note that this `+`-argument syntax is also valid for opening a file from the
command line, so

```
$ vim + filename
```

works as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I'd use:

```
nnoremap <silent><F2> :edit<bar>$<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3anormal) to use the normal-mode [<kbd>G</kbd> motion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#G):

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F2> :edit<CR>:norm! G<CR>
```

Perhaps better would be to use the [`:$`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3a%24) command to go to the end of the file:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F2> :edit<CR>:$<CR>
```

Comment: Perhaps, even better would be to use `:$` in the `+`-argument of the `:edit` command: `:e+$`.  (See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975640/vim-how-to-create-key-mapping-to-edit-and-jump-to-last-line/7976046#7976046) for details.)

Answer (score 2):

You can chain commands in a map by using `<bar>`.  This mapping does what you want:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F2> :edit <bar> :normal! G<enter>
```

It's important to use `normal!` instead of `normal` in mappings/scripts because the prior will not take user defined mappings into account.  Even if there is a mapping for `G` in this case, vim will treat `G` as if it were not mapped at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim `'|'` can be used to separate commands, much like many flavors of Linux/Unix. For more information about the use of the bar check out `:help bar`

Example:

`:edit | normal! G`

If you wish to use this in a key mapping You may find that your `~/.vimrc` doesn't like maps utilizing `|`, or `\|`. In order to make this work use the equivalent `<bar>` instead.